# What is the alternative to using /{friendlist-id}/members in v2.2 of the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My application allows a user to manage their friend list. Using v1.0 of the Graph API I am able to retrieve a lot more users than when using v2.2. I am curious to know if there is an alternative solution to getting a list of members to a an authenticated user's friendlist.